# How can I tell TypeScript that I am handling the case where an string is used to access an inexistent property on an object?

Tags: typescript

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQAkFgCYBtYDOqA3sKqgK4GEBcqAYhWEhCAPZgA0ZqYbE9Nk2x1GzVh2ABfYMCQcCEVAAsseWhjX4YRALwkeVDQAoAlKl0A+ElM6oefAUJx0zF68Rky5CpRBggALaBUNgACggQynSKAWAA5haoAEQEbCFR4PHygVlwMOkwUACOFFCKyQDcsvJgiqhIymzUYJg42hY8EACeAA5QbHCoBRTQMADa-kEh4ZHKALqoAIS6+snCUHDgock85AD8w0JjkwHBoRFR83uodKrthAB0joLC1T51SiNjSaTkRjo7longCCNIgA) is a reproducible example in TypeScript playground to base my question off of.

I get a TypeScript error for the code `router[trimmedPath]`:

> Error:(63, 14) TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Router'.
>     No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Router'.

`trimmedPath` comes from an HTTP request and can be anything, so it is typed as string. In the code above, I just call `router[trimmedPath]`, because if the `trimmedPath` is something not on the `router` object, I do handle this case.

But how should I handle this? Should I just tell TS to ignore that line?

Comment: Could you please edit your code to constitute a [mcve] where the only issue present is the one you are facing?  It's not fun having to fix [all the errors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEj4NwiXdAbB7ALgZ1HAZqApgJ23bKAFjphJAFDkDGcAdkgqFYXEprQBICGtAJjDlABecqFAIAngAdM6UHgCuCHAG0E2AJYBbLZl4AFLgkIBdUAEIhQ0ACIFfTGg209N0WNAB+eXCWr12roGRqbuYgBcoIQ8-DhIAHS0iABivnwA3JTOythoXFSkAEq+OaAA3u5SzgDmkdx8AtiZYgpsBHUxjc2gXLxazgCqbUgdDTjdCHAA1uwjoPWxTeQAvpQgoAAijs6k2JgAjgqYDD5+2NR0J4o5kcVnwuWVNZHRYwTxVbTVADTurXEvTpxeL-Ai-MS9fq0IYAqJA96QwbDcHiaazQFvBKTGb0FaZIA) just to get to a starting point.

Comment: @jcalz absolutely will do. Quick question: I've been using TS for a year now, and I can't seem to advance beyond simple type constructs. What's a good resource to really learn TS besides reading the documentation?

Comment:  I'm not really sure... I spend a lot of time looking though [the GitHub issues](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues) because a lot of interesting things happen in there, but I don't know that I'd recommend someone learn that way.

Comment: And here's my [guess](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgOwCYBsICcoF4oG8oAWAXFAM7DoCWCA5lAL4DcAUEhAMYpzrTsD2CclHR8ArsAwkASmInoWbTt14ChFSgFsNEJAAU4wYmXW0FHLjyj9BwQolQZSJfAj7AAYmOQl4yNJiZmZmo5ADM4dmgZcQw8ZigoMGoaH3t-FgTRUkdUvwwMqDgkDWoAVWz0J1g0-PioYD4AawhBXId5OoBtNwIMAGkIEFIAWTgQACMIEnIqWgBdNv8oAB8oUWQIUOodFnog6yF2Aj5shF927GFZDE71LR19QzmV1YIayoA6Vw8vJBYgA) about what you're trying to do.  If that works I'll make it an answer; otherwise I'll await your [mcve] (or someone else might get to it).  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz yep your guess is right. So basically you need to add an index to tell TS about all the possible types of values for the properties. You must be explicit that you want 'undefined' to be a possibility

Comment: @evianpring I'm a typescript SME/lead professionally and I've got some time to kill. Want help advancing past simple type constructs? https://tlk.io/paarth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following definitions:

```
interface Handlers {
  users: Function,
  notFound: Function,
}

const handlers: Handlers = {
  users: () => {}, 
  notFound: () => {}
}
```

I'd probably make a `Router` interface with an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) so that the compiler knows that `router` might have arbitrary `string`-keyed properties holding other `Function` values.  In order to keep strict null/undefined safety, the value type of this index signature should be `Function | undefined`:

```
interface Router {
  users: Function,
  [otherPossibleKeys: string]: Function | undefined;
}

const router: Router = {
  users: handlers.users
}
```

Then you can use this with no error:

```
const trimmedPath: string = "somethingcomingfromrequest";

const chosenHandler =
  typeof router[trimmedPath] !== "undefined"
    ? router[trimmedPath]
    : handlers.notFound;
```

But a wrinkle: note that `chosenHandler` is inferred to be `Function | undefined`.  That's because even though `router[trimmedPath]` has been checked explicitly, bracket-notation access using a non-literal index (`trimmedPath` is of type `string`) [does not act as a type guard](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530) and so `router[trimmedPath]` afterward is still considered `Function | undefined`.  (The issue is considered a bug or a design limitation; it is easy enough to fix but compiler performance suffers).

But take heart, there is a construct which works the same at runtime but is properly typed:

```
const definedHandler = router[trimmedPath] || handlers.notFound;
```

That works because `Function` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and `undefined` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), and since `x || y` evaluates to `x` if `x` is truthy and `y` otherwise, `definedHandler` will definitely be `Function`.

So that's my recommendation here.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQAkFgCYBtYDOqA3sKqgK4GEBcqAYhWEhCAPZgA0ZqYbE9Nk2x1GzVh24BfYMCQcCEVAAsseWhjX4YRALwkeVDQAoAlKl0A+ElM6oefAUJx0zF68RkzQkWIhSoAEpC0DAG5EY6okws7Fw8ANr8yrAACmwEBCAARvgA0lAAngR0ijDgAOYAutHicagAPpQ4UHDgUNgA3MDe8mCKqDAhsHTBFKEW4ZTUUSpahAB0kQQ9sn0DEOUAtlsdqQgQyqWblZMARARsu4eV8luVcENbMFAAjhRQimfdcgpKSMoMlAwJgcNoLDwIIUAA5QNhwQbDGAJE47PYHZRVVAAQl0+jOwla7WwZx45AA-IjxrAUdtdth9ocqmTUHRVGDFo5BMJugB6XmoRQgXC4BgxCRgRrNbBEsAdNZ-VAytpy7Cg9RhfRDanI1H0xmYxpNdkaggLLnOLrAfliuocWRAA)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by giving your router an index signature. I've modified your example slightly [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQAkFgCYBtYDOqA3sKqgK4GEBcqAYhWEhCAPZgA0ZqYbE9Nk2x1GzVh2ABfYMCQcCEVAAsseWhjX4YRALwkeVDQAoAlKl0A+ElM6oefAUJx0zF68Rky5CpRBggALaBUNgACggQynSKAWAA5haoAEQEbCFR4PHygVlwMOkwUACOFFCKyQDcsuDQ8MhoEVGYONoG5ADaAA6R0aixWQC6okws7FzSsvJgiqgFFHV0Tcot6jBJpORGOnSqrYQAdNsEkz4zSkjKbNRgq226PBAAnl1QbHBzQnUd-kEh4b1BqgAIS6fTJYRQODgULJHjkAD8nwWsB+AWCoWWg3hqF2WkOjkEwmqwCAA).

```
interface PathHandler {
  [path: string]: Function,
}
const router: PathHandler = {
  users: handlers.users
}
```